# Using BulkRecordUpdater

Tags: rally, appsdk2

When attepming to use a Rally.data.BulkRecordUpdater, I ran into a few problems.  First of all, the documentation is incorrect.  The example provided:

```
Rally.data.BulkRecordUpdater({
    records: [record1, record2],
    propertiesToUpdate: {
        Parent: '/hierarchicalrequirement/123.js'
    },
    success: function(readOnlyRecords){
        //all updates finished, except for given read only records
    },
    scope: this
});
```

should be:

```
Rally.data.BulkRecordUpdater.updateRecords({
    records: [record1, record2],
    propertiesToUpdate: {
        Parent: '/hierarchicalrequirement/123.js'
    },
    success: function(readOnlyRecords){
        //all updates finished, except for given read only records
    },
    scope: this
});
```

Secondly, when trying to use this method to update records I keep getting an error for being unable to call the method 'get' - I am assuming that this is because the records I am providing are not in the correct format.  I am simply calling this on records I pull from a wsapi query.  I have tried putting the object inside of another object:

```
{data: record}
```

but it still does not seem to help.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: adding `{data: record}` was an attempt to turn each one into a record - is there any short and easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out the doc issue.  I'm filing a defect to fix this.

The records should be instances of Rally.domain.WsapiModel.  If you are using Rally.data.WsapiDataStore to retrieve them then you should be all set.  Are you doing something different?

For what it's worth, we're also currently working on another, better way to do batch updates of records.  Look for it in a future SDK!

Answer (score 0):

See this example if it helps

```
            _justFunction: function(_childObj) {
                records = ["abc", "xyz"];
                var store = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                    data: records,
                    listeners: {
                        load: that._updateAll,
                        scope: that
                    },     
                });
            },  
            _updateAll: function(store,data) {
                Rally.data.BulkRecordUpdater.updateRecords({
                    records: data,
                    propertiesToUpdate: {
                        Parent: _newParent.get("_ref")
                    },
                    success: function(readOnlyRecords){
                        //all updates finished, except for given read only records
                    },
                    scope: that
                });
            },
```